# AngularJS: .value persistance

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following:

**AngularJS:**

```
angular.module('app', [])

.value('userData', {})

.factory('AuthService', function (userData) {

    $http.put('/login', {
    ...
    })

    .then(function onSuccess(res) {
        userData = res.data.user
    })

})

.controller('Dashboard', function (userData) {
    $scope.user = userData
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="Dashboard"> {{ user.name }} </div>
```

Should `userData` be populated when it is time for `{{ user.name }}` ? Should `userData` persist through a refresh? If the goal is to display information received from the API specific to the user, What other options do I have besides storing `res.data.user` to local storage?

Comment: may be something like this to cache the result $http({ cache: true, url: '/login', method: 'POST'})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct assignments like

```
userData = res.data.user;
```

break JS references, meaning anything that referenced the variable won't get the new value.

A better option in my opinion is to save a reference to the promise in your factory

```
.factory('AuthService', function ($http) {
    return $http.put('/login', {
        ...
    }).then(function (res) {
        return res.data.user;
    });
})
```

The HTTP request will only run once when your factory is created but the promise will be saved against the factory name. Then your controller (or anything else) can simply use

```
$scope.user = 'Loading...'; // if you want to show something right away
AuthService.then(function(userData) {
    $scope.user = userData;
});
```

Comment: So you approach is to only access the user data after the factory is completely finished running, implying the callback from the PUT has finished?

Comment: You can access the promise stored in the `AuthService` factory at any time but it will only resolve with a value once the PUT request has completed. Once it has, any call to `AuthService.then()` will resolve instantly

Comment: @CiscoKidx then you haven't used the code I wrote. Do you have `return $http.put...` in your factory code?

Comment: Yes. AuthService is a tad more complex than articulated in the original question.  AuthService: https://gist.github.com/CiscoKidxx/b8123e34843ca141b155b52b879fe2ff

Comment: Controller:  `AuthService.user.then(function(user) {
  $scope.user = user;
 });` `Also tried:  AuthService.then(function(user) {
  $scope.user = user;
 });`

Comment: @CiscoKidx then have the `user` method return the promise. The basic idea is that any value that is assigned asynchronously should be wrapped in a promise.

Comment: The `user` method IS returning the promise I thought.

Comment: @CiscoKidx You would need `AuthService.user().then`, not `AuthService.user.then`. Also, you're welcome

Comment: Bingo. Noob alert ->